# How to highlight Selected variables and object in Acess IDE

Tags: vba, microsoft-access

I was wondering if there is a way or a plugin or anything that will make me able to highlight variables in Access IDE . I mean like when I select a variable or a object or a method , I want to see it occurrence in the current document , just like any other IDE

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to highlight them all at the same time, but you can use the `Ctrl-F3` shortcut to jump to the next occurrence of the **text** you have selected. It doesn't jump to the same identifier necessarily (if you select `foo` it will jump to the middle of `gefooed`).

You can also use `Shift-F2` to jump to the definition of an identifier.

You could also look for IDE addons such as MZ-Tools and Rubberduck which may have that or similar features (caveat: I have not used these).